# Keep the color of the dropdown button while the cursor is over one of the list items

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to make the dropdown list keep the color when hovering over the content of the list. That is to say, as can be seen when passing the mouse over an element of the bar the button turns blue, I would like the button to remain blue while the user keeps the mouse within the content of the drop-down list.
I'm not very familiar with css and html so I haven't been able to find the solution, I would appreciate any guidance.

```js
const info = '[\n  {\n    "name": "Dropdown 1",\n    "dropdown": [\n      {\n        "name": "Google",\n        "link": "www.google.com"\n      },\n      {\n        "name": "Coin Market Cap",\n        "link": "www.coinmarketcap.com"\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  {\n    "name": "Dropdown 2",\n    "dropdown": [\n      {\n        "name": "Google",\n        "link": "www.google.com"\n      },\n      {\n        "name": "Coin Market Cap",\n        "link": "www.coinmarketcap.com"\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  {\n    "name": "Dropdown 3",\n    "dropdown": [\n      {\n        "name": "Google",\n        "link": "www.google.com"\n      },\n      {\n        "name": "Coin Market Cap",\n        "link": "www.coinmarketcap.com"\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  {\n    "name": "Dropdown 4",\n    "dropdown": [\n      {\n        "name": "Google",\n        "link": "www.google.com"\n      },\n      {\n        "name": "Coin Market Cap",\n        "link": "www.coinmarketcap.com"\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  {\n    "name": "Dropdown 5",\n    "dropdown": [\n      {\n        "name": "Google",\n        "link": "www.google.com"\n      },\n      {\n        "name": "Coin Market Cap",\n        "link": "www.coinmarketcap.com"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n]\n';

function LoadMenu(jsonStr) {
        const data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        $.each(data, function (i, option) {
          $("#menu").append(
            $("<li/>")
              .addClass("parent")
              .append($("<button/>").addClass("botones").append(option.name))
              .append(
                $("<div/>")
                  .addClass("wrapper")
                  .append(
                    $("<ul/>")
                      .attr("id", `dropdown-${i}`)
                      .addClass("dropdown__content")
                  )
              )
          );
          $.each(option.dropdown, function (j, link) {
            $(`#dropdown-${i}`).append(
              $("<li/>").append(
                $("<a/>").append(link.name).attr("href", link.link)
              )
            );
          });
        });
      }
      LoadMenu(info);

      $(function () {
        // whenever we hover over a menu item that has a submenu
        $("li.parent").on("mouseover", function () {
          var $menuItem = $(this),
            $submenuWrapper = $("> .wrapper", $menuItem);

          // grab the menu item's position relative to its positioned parent
          var menuItemPos = $menuItem.position();

          // place the submenu in the correct position relevant to the menu item
          $submenuWrapper.css({
            bottom: menuItemPos.bottom,
            left: menuItemPos.left + Math.round($menuItem.outerWidth() * 0),
          });
        });
      });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.principal {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.dropdown__content {
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
}

.dropdown__content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  
}

.botones {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  color: #0b2971;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
}

.botones:hover {
  background-color: #0b2971;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 70px;
}

li {
  position: static;
}

li .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

li:hover > .wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 70px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}

.LogoutAndUser {
  margin: 10px 2px;
  float: right;
  color: #0b2971;
}

.LogoutAndUser a {
  color: #0b2971;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                 <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>            


  </head>
  <body>
  
  
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home"><img src="https://security.arizona.edu/sites/default/files/World%20Wide%20Technology%20Horizontal%20Logo%20Full%20Color.png" height="50"></a>
    <ul class="principal" id="menu"></ul>
    <div class = "LogoutAndUser">
      <a style="text-decoration: none;"> User 1 </a>  
      <a> <i class='fa fa-sign-out'> Cerrar sesion</i></a>        
    </div>
    
    
    
  </div>
  


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown:hover .button {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This should work, just change class name above in my code to classes of your dropdown and button.